# Are there wizards with speech impediments?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

As we can see [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/171695/89365) inflection is very important in spell-casting.

Can lisping wizard cast a spell (without harm to himself)? Can someone with another pronunciation problem?

Can we find this type of wizard in books?

Comment: Well they can do non-verbal incantations.

Comment: This is a dupe of two related questions; Firstly, wizards can cast spells wordlessly if they need to (and have sufficient skill) and secondly, wizards can correct mundane ailments like lisping

Comment: Seplenic isn't an English word.

Comment: A lisp is not the same as muteness.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - The third dupe target specifically addresses an inability to pronounce words correctly.

Comment: @Valorum Fair enough. I think it's a dupe of the third one.

Comment: Yes.  Quirrel stutters and stammers